# Python - Decode an already decoded string?

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to convert a value received from a NetFlowv9 record, more specifically, the 'IN_BYTES=' value.
The problem is that I can get the value but it comes in string format, meaning it's already decoded and the values received are something like:
b'\x00\x03q\x1d'
And I assign this value to a variable like so:

```
numOfBytes = (flowEntry[flowEntry.index("IN_BYTES=b") + 9:flowEntry.index("IN_PKTS=")-1])
```

I need this value in int, however, as I stated, this is a 'str' object and therefore I can't seem to 'decode' it again to 'utf-8' or get values from 'list()?

Here's what I've tried so far:
Decoding 'numOfBytes' to utf-8:

```
numOfBytesDec = numOfBytes.decode('utf-8')
```

But I obviously get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I've also tried converting to list:

```
numOfBytesList = list(numOfBytes)
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What's happening is that numOfBytes = "b'\x00\x03q\x1d'" and since it is a string I can't manipulate it to convert that to a number.
What I would expect was something like:

```
numOfBytes = b'\x00\x03q\x1d'
numOfBytesList = list(numOfBytes)
```

and 'numOfBytesList' should return something like [0, 3, 113, 29] so I could calculate afterwards 0*(255*255*255)+3*(255*255)+113*255+29 for example..

Is there any way I could convert the string to a usuable Bytes object?
TLDR: Is there a way to convert `"b'\x00\x03q\x1d'"` to `b'\x00\x03q\x1d'`

Comment: you could `eval()`(use `ast.literal_eval` and not the built in eval) your string, that would turn it into `bytes`

Comment: You could use struct https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html    
`struct.unpack('i', b'\x00\x03q\x1d')` EDIT: I misread. Use what Nullman said.

Comment: Seems like it @nikolay-manolov , couldn't find it and I searched for ages...
Edit: However, the solution presented doesn't work in my case

Comment: @tegraze why is it not working ?
There are actually to steps.
The first is to use `ast.literal_eval` to get from `"b'\x00\x03q\x1d'"` to `b'\x00\x03q\x1d'` and then use `struct.unpack` to get to number(s)

Comment: @NikolayManolov It gives me `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character` and as stated in the other question you linked, I can't take any chances in terms of security as this is a part of an IDS :(

Comment: Right, I get that, but that is why @Nullman suggested, and also referenced in the other question is to use `ast.literal_eval` https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval which only evaluates literals, which is safe, no code will be executed.

Comment: Alright security out of the way.. however, that error I got from using ast.literal_eval(numOfBytes) :(

Comment: I just tried `ast.literal_eval("b'\x00\x03q\x1d'")` and got an error `ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes`. Then tried `ast.literal_eval("b'\x03q\x1d'")` which returned `b'\x03q\x1d'`. Using python 3.7

Comment: @NikolayManolov In a typical scenario, you would actually do `ast.literal_eval("b'\\x00\\x03q\\x1d'")`, which will work. OP posted the string you used, but it's quite likely that they actually meant `"b'\\x00\\x03q\\x1d'"`, which is what you get when you call `str(b'\x00\x03q\x1d')` without specifying an encoding. Or when you `print()` it to a file.

Comment: @NikolayManolov managed to get it to work with ast.literal_eval() even with null bytes so I dont have to strip them either.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `bytes` function https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/bytes

Your string `"b'\x00\x03q\x1d'"` has a leading `"b'"` and a trailing `"'"` that you don't need, so

```
list(bytes(numOfBytes[2:-2], 'utf8'))
```

should:

- strip the first two and the last characters of the string
- decode using utf8
- convert to a list

Comment: `numOfBytes[2:]` should be `numOfBytes[2:-1]` because he also has a closing `'`

Comment: When using `bytes` I actually get all the values of each character on the original string :(
In my case I can take the leading `b'` and the last `'`by changing the line
`numOfBytes = (flowEntry[flowEntry.index("IN_BYTES=b") + 9:flowEntry.index("IN_PKTS=")-1])`
to
`numOfBytes = (flowEntry[flowEntry.index("IN_BYTES=b") + 11:flowEntry.index("IN_PKTS=")-2])`

Comment: @tegraze what version of python are you using?

Comment: @SimonCrane I'm using version Python 3.5.2

Comment: @tegraze I am using Python 3.7.2 and when I run my code I get the output `[0, 3, 113]`.  Is this not the desired behaviour?  you said "and 'numOfBytesList' should return something like [0, 3, 113, 29] so I could calculate afterwards 0*(255*255*255)+3*(255*255)+113*255+29 for example."

Comment: @SimonCrane using that I would get something like [99, 97, 23, 34, 45, 34,87, 34, 21, 23, 54] (example numbers) and not just 3 or 4 values...
However, using ast.literal_eval() without stripping the border characters I managed to producce the Desired list.

I know what you mean, if I replicate it on python shell I can execute it as intended, however that doesn't work in my code as it probably isn't even in utf-8 format or something..

Edit: In fact, if I try it afterwars, it gives me an error saying that utf-8 can't handle some characters so yeah it's likely not utf-8 and my tag was wrong